# Change airflow-ui from logging INFO to WARN - Works for airflow-scheduler?

Tags: logging, airflow, airflow-scheduler

After doing some intense research, it is clear that it is possible to change airflow

> [core]
>   logging_level = WARN

Since version 1.9: [logging level airflow 1.9 commit](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/3c3a65a3fe2edbd7eee1d736735194a1ca14962a)

However, I can see that `airflow-ui` still logs `INFO` when I run airflow. This change only seem to cover `airflow-scheduler` to change `INFO` to `WARN`?

I can't find any documentation anywhere that suggests you to be able to also change the logging level of the `airflow-ui`.

I did a quick test where I wrote:

> webserver_logging_level = WARN

With of course no result, wild guess.

I have also tried to add it like this:

```
[core]
logging_level = WARN

[webserver] 
logging_level = WARN

[scheduler] 
logging_level = WARN
```

So is there any way to actually make the `airflow-ui` to only log `WARN` as `airflow-scheduler` does with `logging_level`?

Comment: Running into the same issue. We also have issues with the scheduler starting if I set `logging_level = WARN`. Once i revert back to `INFO` the scheduler fires up just fine.

Comment: So for us the problem is that the `INFO` logging occurs for the `airflow-ui` but it works for `airflow-scheduler`. `airflow-scheduler` is the most important but still a pain that `airflow-ui` keeps logging.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Want to change the log level of Airflow Webserver from INFO to ERROR.